# Smoothing out of rough plots

Tags: matlab, uniform, exponential-distribution

I want to draw some plots in Matlab.

*Details:* For class **1**, **p(x|c1)** is uniform for **x** between **[2, 4]** with the parameters **a = 1** and **b = 4**. For class **2**,  **p(x|c2)** is exponential with parameter **lambda = 1**. Besides **p(c1) = p(c2) = 0.5** I would like to draw a sketch of the two class densities multiplied by **P(c1)** and **P(c2)** respectively, as
a function of **x**, clearly showing the optimal decision boundary (or boundaries).

I have the solution for this problem, this is what the writer did (and *I want to get*), but there's no Matlab code, so I want to do it all by myself.

[image: IMAGE 1]

And this is what I drew.

[image: IMAGE 2]

And this is the MATLAB code I wrote.

```
x=0:1:8;

pc1 = 0.5;
px_given_c1 = exppdf(x,1);
px_given_c2 = unifpdf(x,2,4);

figure;
plot(x,px_given_c1,'g','linewidth',3);
hold on;
plot(x,px_given_c2,'r','linewidth',3);
axis([0 8 0 0.5]);
legend('P(x|c_1)','P(x|c_2)');

figure;
plot(x,px_given_c1.*pc1,'g','linewidth',3);
hold on;
plot(x,px_given_c2.*(1-pc1),'r','linewidth',3);
axis([0 8 0 0.5]);
legend('P(x|c_1)P(c_1)','P(x|c_2)P(c_2)');
```

As you can see, they are almost smiliar, but I am having problem with this uniform distribution, which is drawn in red. How can I change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably change `x=0:1:8;` to something like `x=0:1e-3:8;` or even `x=linspace(0,8,1000);` to have finer plotting. This increases number of points in vectors (and therefore *line segments*) Matlab will use to plot.

---

*Explanation:* Matlab works with **line segments** when it does plotting!

By writing `x=0:1:8;` you create vector `[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]` that is of length 9, and by applying `exppdf` and `unifpdf` respectively you create two vectors of the same length derived from original vector. So basically you get vectors `[exppdf(0) exppdf(1) ... exppdf(8)]` and `[unifpdf(0) unifpdf(1) ... unifpdf(8)]`.

When you issue `plot` command afterwards Matlab plots only line segments (8 of them in this case because there are 9 points):

- from **(x(1), px_given_c1(1))** to **(x(2), px_given_c1(2))**,
- ...
- from **(x(8), px_given_c1(8))** to **(x(9), px_given_c1(9))**.

Comment: thank you so much! it did work! but can you explain me why this simple code changes everything?

Comment: @MuratArat I've provided an explanation!

Comment: But, x=0:1:8, does not create the vector x =[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] ?

Comment: You meant to say that `x=0:1:8` didn't create `x=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]` I suppose... You were right; I made mistake which is fixed now!

Comment: yes, ok, sorry for bothering you, I was almost aware of that mistake, but as I said, I am so new to coding so I thought there was a feature that I don't know. Much obliged for your help.